# slow wifi internet when connected to other bluetooth device

Tags: wireless, internet, bluetooth

My wifi internet is very slow when I connect bluetooth speaker. However, in windows 8 internet is fast even if I am connected to bluetooth speaker.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Output for:
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0026 SiGma Micro Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 09da:c10a A4 Tech Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2881 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed by running in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0"
```

Then reboot and test.